# jqgrid change position of subgrid or add a subgrid icon to custom column and not anywhere else?

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I'm new to jqgrid. I want to create a jqgrid with subgrid for which I have got the code from trirand.com. But in the example the subgrid icon to show the child row or subgrid is by default in the 1st place of all rows.

How can we change the position of the icon to any other column such that the column data text and the (+) icon are in the same cell of table. As my data is in JSON format and the icon position requirement can change. On click of that I need to show the relevant subgrid.

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on the *version* of jqGrid, which you use and the **fork** of jqGrid. Tony Tomov develops commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) and I develop [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), available completely free of charge.

I rewrote many parts of old code of jqGrid in free jqGrid fork. One of the features: one can move `"subgrid"` column to any other place in the grid. One need just use `remapColumns` or better new `remapColumnsByName` method to reorder the columns. One can skip the last columns of `remapColumnsByName`, which places will be not changed or to skip first *standard* column, like `"rn"` column, where one can see the row numbers (if the option `rownumbers: true` is used). The demo
https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/o1L8k2k6/ uses the following call

```
.jqGrid("remapColumnsByName", ["name", "invdate", "subgrid"], true);
```

to move `"subgrid"` column after the columns `"name"` and `"invdate"`. One will see the results like

[image]

If you need to place the "+"/"-" icon inside of the other column then you should use, first of all, custom formatter to place the icon inside of the column and then you can use `beforeSelectRow` to detect the click inside of the column. Additionally you can use `.jqGrid("hideCol", "subgrid")` to hide the standard subgrid column. The code of custom formatter could be, for example,

```
formatter: function (cellValue) {
    // place the icon using Font Awesome icons (http://fontawesome.io/)
    // the the original data itself. One should encode the data
    // with respect of $.jgrid.htmlEncode for example to be sure that
    // ANY data could be correctly displayed in the column (like ' symbol)
    return "<span class='mysubgrid fa fa-fw fa-plus'></span>" +
        "&nbsp;" + $.jgrid.htmlEncode(cellValue);
}
```

The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/o1L8k2k6/2/ uses additionally the following code of `beforeSelectRow` to process opening/closing the subgrid

```
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    var $target = $(e.target), $subgridTd;
    if ($target.hasClass("mysubgrid")) {
        $subgridTd = $target.closest("tr.jqgrow>td")
            .siblings("td")
            .filter(".ui-sgcollapsed");

        // simulate opening/closing of the subgrid
        $target.removeClass("fa-minus fa-plus"); // remove both classes
        $target.addClass(
            $subgridTd.hasClass("sgexpanded") ?
                "fa-plus" :
                "fa-minus"
        );
        // simulate click on the original subgrid button
        $subgridTd.find(".sgbutton").click();
    }
    return true; // allow selection of the row
}
```

which looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you can use the methods, which toggles the subgrid. These methods are called expandSubGridRow, collapseSubGridRow or toggleSubGridRow.

For more information see the [Guriddo documentation here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/subgrid/#methods)

You can bind a click on the desired cell (using the formatter or cellattr events) to toggle the subgrid row

Comment: dude but i cannot find any help about how to apply the subgrid plus sign to any position

Comment: As I say in my answer use formatter or cellattr event to add plus sign. You will need to add this manually and bind a click or use onCellSelect event which will execute toggllSubGridRow. The position of default plus sign of subgrid can not be changed